# How to use Django-Filter together with Django-Taggit (to filter posts by tags)?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

I would like to filter my posts by tags. How could I use it together with Django filter? My current situation:

```
#models.py

from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


#forms.py

class PostForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'


#filter.py

class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

   class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = ['title', 'text']


#views.py

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    myFilter = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=posts)
    posts = myFilter.qs
    context = {'posts':posts, 'myFilter':myFilter, 'tags':tags}
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

Is there a way to include tags to the forms.py?

edit: added models.py. The "tags" are imported from taggit, but cannot be simply added to the fields in forms.py

Comment: What is the relation between Post and Tag? Can you add model definitions to your question? I guess you should pass wrong queryset in filter, need to filter over Post.objects first.

Comment: @DenizKaplan I have extended my text with an example of my models.py. The Tag is simply imported from Taggit through 'tags = TaggableManager()'. Unfortunately, I do not quite get what you meant with the last part of your reply.

Comment: As I understand, you need to filter your posts with some tags. Where is the tag names information you want to filter? `myFilter = PostFilter(request.GET, queryset=posts.filter(tag__name__in=tag_names))` The last part is about changing the filter with this code. But you need tag_names to filter.

Comment: @DenizKaplan Ok, I understand. The issue here is that I create the filter form on my index.html with {{ myFilter.form }} which derives from #forms.py (updated my question to include this file) and here I cannot include 'tags' because it raises an error due to being TaggableManager() and not a normal field. This is where I loose sight how to achieve what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have searched a little bit, can you try `from taggit.forms import TagWidget` this widget for tags? Then you need to change widget definition in the form. Here is the link for widget part: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by the tags name

```
class FilterName(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Modelname
        fields = {'tags__name':{'exact'}}
```